# How to fix @{DisplayName=Firstname Lastname}

Tags: powershell

`@{DisplayName=Firstname Lastname}` needs to be just 'Firstname Lastname' because `get-mailbox -identity '@{DisplayName=Firstname Lastname}` won't work.

I've tried using the -replace cmdlet to remove text.

```
$Olduser = Get-MsolUser -all | Where-Object {$_.BlockCredential -eq $True -and $_.isLicensed -eq $false} | Select-Object displayName,userPrincipalName,BlockCredential,isLicensed

$OldUser | fl *
```

Using the -replace, I expected that the output will be without '@{DisplayName}'

---

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{DisplayName=X X}" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter". Error: "Cannot conve
rt the "@{DisplayName=X X}" value of type "Deserialized.Selected.Microsoft.Online.Administration.User" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter"."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: What is the output of $olduser?

Comment: I was able to replicate this by running `Get-Mailbox -Identity $OldUser`.  `-Identity` parameter takes a value rather than a custom object. You need to use `Get-Mailbox -Identity $OldUser.DisplayName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an object type with properties to a parameter (`-Identity`) that expects just a value. As a result, PowerShell converts that object into a string, which results in the value `@{DisplayName=Firstname Lastname}`. If you access the `DisplayName` property before passing it into the `-Identity` parameter, your issue will be resolved.

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity $OldUser.DisplayName
# Or
$OldUser.DisplayName | Get-Mailbox
```

You can replicate a similar behavior by typing the following at the console:

```
[string]$OldUser
```

Comment: Ugh... Thanks!!! I was thinking way too far. Thank you for the last push to get it solved.